# How To Get Rid Of "Upgrade to OS X El Capitan" Notification?

Tags: macos, upgrade, notifications

The upgrade notification gets more and more intrusive day by day. Now there is no option to be "Reminded Tomorrow" or "Skip This" anymore.

[image]

Now one *could* just turn on "Do Not Disturb" feature from System Preferences between 00:01 and 23:59 (or something similar more suitable for the sleep pattern of the dear reader). However, there are still some notifications I'd love to see.

So, the question is: How to get rid of this particular notification (for good, preferably) ie. how to just use whatever I've got installed and not upgrade for the time being?

Comment: One way to do this is to actually upgrade your Mac to El Capitan. :-O    In all seriousness, I have a Yosemite Mac at home, and I do not get this pop-up.

Comment: I think that would be ruled out by the caveat at the end of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](http://create.pro/blog/hide-os-x-yosemite-update-notification-disable-yosemite-upgrade-reminder/) which specifies how to disable the Yosemite update,  go to the App Store, click the Updates tab, then Right-click on the El Capitan update banner at the top and select Hide Update.